# AWS CodeDeploy to second subnet fails

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm experiencing some issues these days with CodeDeploy and EC2 instances. I have a VPC with two public subnets (VPC: 10.0.0.0/16 , subnet1: 10.0.0.0/24, subnet2: 10.0.1.0/24), both having assigned an internet gateway. I deploy an EC2 instance to both of them with the correct roles. The problem I have though, is that when using CodeDeploy to deploy to the instance in the first subnet (10.0.0.0/24) it works all the way but when I do the same thing to the instance in the second subnet it remains stuck in pending with no step completed and then times out. Both subnets seem to be the same as configuration but I have no idea why CodeDeploy works with the first one but not the second.

Do you have any idea? What could I check? Is there an obvious reason why it fails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing obvious from your description so just a couple of points to check:

- Are both EC2 instances registered in the same *Deployment Group*?
- Is the *CodeDeploy agent* running on the 2<sup>nd</sup> instance?
- Are they both in the same *Security Group*?
- Are they both built from the *same AMI* using the *same automation script*? E.g. through AutoScaling Launch Config? (this is to ensure that both EC2 are 100% identical)
- What if you create *another instance* in the 1<sup>st</sup> subnet - would deployment to that work? (this is to determine whether *any* second deployment fails or if it's caused by the subnet configuration)
- What *deployment type* do you use? Maybe the first deployment isn't successfully completed so the second one never starts. Can you try *all-at-once* deployment that kicks of on all instances at the same time?

Either the instances are not identical, or the subnets have different config, or security settings are not identical, or something else is different between them.

*Update:* Or your AMI has a built-in configuration made for a specific AZ or subnet, as it turns out. AMIs should *auto-configure* from DHCP when they launch. They shouldn't have any network-related settings hardcoded, that way they will be usable in different subnets and AZs.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: Thank you. Checked and everythung is fine. Also deleted both subnets and created only the one 10.0.1.0/24 and it doesn't work. But as soon as I add the second one now 10.0.0/24 it does.

Comment: New test. Created a new vpc altogether (10.0.1.0/24) with only one subnet 10.0.1.0/24. Ad it doesn't work. Apparently it only works when instance in 10.0.0.0/24

Comment: @Andrew that’s really odd. The subnets must have different settings - route tables, IGW attachment, automatic public IP assignment, DNS / DHCP options, something like that. Or some IAM policies that specify 10.0.0.0/24? CodeDeploy is definitely not restricted to any IP addr.

Comment: route table is the same one (thus same IGW assigned to both), automatic public IP assignment disabled for both (the instances have it enabled), IAM policies are administrator level to avoid any issue due to that.

Comment: @Andrew Are the CodeDeploy agents successfully connected to the service on both instances? I don’t have CodeDeploy stack at hand now but I guess it’s visible in the console and also in some log files on the instance. Also while you’re looking at the log files is there any sign of any activity in the logs on the non-working instances during deploy attempt?

Comment: I dug more and I discovered that the image I used was made for a specific availability zone. When I created the instance in another availability zone based on that image the machine wouldn't know how to handle the network and thus code deploy failed as well. So no issue at network level, it was machine and agent related ultimately. Thank you for help!

Comment: @Andrew Glad that you figured out the root cause. I have added that to the response. If you can upvote it and accept as correct that'll be much appreciated :)